# .NET Maui Get screen Y and X

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I cant seem to find how to get the screen size of the screen.
I tried the Xamarin forms way:

```
mainDisplayInfo.Height;
```

Maui for windows doesnt work like this, anyone know how I can do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since Xamarin Essentials is now part of .NET MAUI as well, you should be able to get all the info you need with `Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo` and all the properties in there like: `Width` and `Height`.

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/essentials/device-display all APIs should be the same except for the namespace where they live.

Comment: "Should" is the key word here, the problem is that it doesn't return all the correct values. For example, density/scale: On windows, regardless of your actual device scale, density always returns 1.

Comment: @RichardD. Is this still the same...

Comment: Yes as of today Jan 24, 2024 (setting 125% scale -> Density = 1)

Comment: There is no `Maui.Essentials`, it's just `Maui` now (though for some reason you need to [manually edit the project file in a text editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/native-essentials?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android) to enable it)

Answer (score 14):

That function is currently sitting in:

```
Microsoft.Maui.Devices.DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo
```

Comment: At present this seems to return all zeros on Windows desktop during the OnAppearing method :(

Answer (score 0):

Use `Window.Height`
More info here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/windows